# Отобрать данные с символами верхнего регистра

Tags: python, строки, pandas, dataframe

Необходимо в таблице оставить только те строки, в которых символами верхнего регистра написано более чем, например, 70% текста.

То есть, на входе имеем таблицу:

```
Text
HELLO
IT IS you
Miss you
HOW are YOU
HAWLETTT co
```

Соответственно, на выходе должно получиться:

```
Text
HELLO
HAWLETTT co
```

Comment: 1) Берем общее количество символов в строке 2) Подсчитываем сколько символов в верхнем регистре 3) Считаем `2)` в процентах 4) Фильтруем данные по значению процентов. Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос ваш код, наверняка одно из перечисленною мною уже у вас в сделано/процессе, а с этим проще будет помочь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [15]: df.loc[df.Text.str.replace(r'[^A-Z]', '').str.len() / df.Text.str.len() >= 0.7]
Out[15]:
          Text
0        HELLO
4  HAWLETTT co
```

Comment: такс, я не подумал, а с русским текстом это должно сработать? у меня что то нет) Я так полагая исправление `^А-Я` поможет:)

Comment: @CR7, для английского и кирилицы: `[^A-ZА-ЯЁ]`